# Why **extra info is not being displayed?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, syntax

why is the manufacturing and the color not being displayed?

What is my mistake?

```
def make_car(brand, model, **extra_info):
    car = {}
    car['brand name'] = brand
    car['model name'] = model
    for key, value in car.items():
        car[key] = value
    return car

car_info = make_car('Mercedes Benz', 'S Class',
                manufacturing='Affalterbach',
                color='blue')

print(car_info)
```

Comment: Because you're iterating over *car*.items()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the `car` variable in line 5 to `extra_info` keyword argument.

**Code:**

```
def make_car(brand, model, **extra_info):
    car = {}
    car["brand name"] = brand
    car["model name"] = model
    for key, value in extra_info.items():  # Use the 'extra_info' keyword argument.
        car[key] = value
    return car


car_info = make_car("Mercedes Benz", "S Class", manufacturing="Affalterbach", color="blue")

print(car_info)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
{'brand name': 'Mercedes Benz', 'model name': 'S Class', 'manufacturing': 'Affalterbach', 'color': 'blue'}
```